# Kind of a closed form for the Möbius function as the number of points on n-dimensional hyperboloids.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, mobius-function

Through experimenting with the Mertens function sum I wrote in Wikipedia I found this formula if you like, for the Möbius function as a sum of the number of points on n-dimensional hyperboloids:

$$\mu(1)=1$$
$$\underset{n > 1}{\mu(n)} =  - \underset{a = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2}} 1 + \underset{ab = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2}} 1 - \underset{abc = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2} \sum_{c \geq 2}} 1 + \underset{abcd = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2} \sum_{c \geq 2} \sum_{d \geq 2}} 1 - \cdots$$

$$=1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0,..$$

Associated Mathematica program:

```
nn = 25;
Table[-Sum[If[a == n, 1, 0], {a, 2, nn}] + 
  Sum[Sum[If[a*b == n, 1, 0], {a, 2, nn}], {b, 2, nn}] - 
  Sum[Sum[Sum[If[a*b*c == n, 1, 0], {a, 2, nn}], {b, 2, nn}], {c, 2, 
    nn}] + Sum[
   Sum[Sum[Sum[If[a*b*c*d == n, 1, 0], {a, 2, nn}], {b, 2, nn}], {c, 
     2, nn}], {d, 2, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]
MoebiusMu[Range[25]]
%% - %
```

How does one prove this formula for $\mu(n)$?

Comment: The proof is not obvious to me, but I used the following three Mathematica functions to verify the relationship up to n=10,000:

mu[n_] := If[n == 1, 1, Sum[(-1)^j dSum[n, j], {j, 1, Log[2, n]}]] where

dSum[n_, j_] := Block[{d, i, dsum = 0},
  If[j == 1,
   If[n != 1, dsum = 1],
   d = Divisors[n]; i = 2;
   While[i <= Length[d], dsum += dSum[n/d[[i]], j - 1]; i++]];
  dsum] with the test function 

testMu[nMax_] := 
 Block[{n = 1}, 
  While[n <= nMax && (mu[n] == MoebiusMu[n]), n++]; {n, MoebiusMu[n], 
   mu[n]}]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not understand how to program it in Mathematica but you meant it as a comment so that is ok.